# How to create queue of events in order by date

Tags: linked-list, queue, eventqueue, discrete-space

I am trying to create a queue of events and I want to be able to insert and delete from the middle of the queue in constant time, something like this:

3446  --- 9493 --- 15969 --- 48381

where the number could be millis from now, or whatnot.

How could I insert an event between the 9493 and 15969 event?

I could use binary search to find the events in the queue with the desired times, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a priority queue:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue

The typical way to implement one is to use a heap; you get `O(log n)` insert time and `O(log n)` delete time (for removing the highest priority item from the queue). Check the Wikipedia page for a list of other potential data structures, some of which have better amortized time.